# AngularJS Jasmine test: scoped variable always undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, jasmine, karma-runner

I am very new to testing in Javascript and am currenly trying to test a controller function.
The function calls a service method which retrieves data from a web sql db.

This is a part of my controller function (it contains 2 callbacks, one for success and another for error):

```
    $scope.getLocations = function () {
        LocationDbService.getAll(
            //Success
            function (tx, results) {

                $scope.numberOfLocations = results.rows.length;
                ...
            },
            //Error
            function () {
                console.log("Error");
            });
    }
```

The test:

```
it('we should be able to retrieve all stored locations',
    function () {
        expect(scope.numberOfLocations).toBeUndefined();
        scope.getLocations();
        expect(scope.numberOfLocations).toBeDefined();
    });
```

beforeEach test:

```
var ctrl, scope, location, locationDbService;
// inject the $controller and $rootScope services
// in the beforeEach block
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $location, LocationDbService) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('LocationsCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
    location = $location;
    locationDbService = LocationDbService;
}));
```

Controller header:

```
.controller('LocationsCtrl', function ($scope, $location, LocationDbService) {
```

When I run the application in the browser (or on my smartphone, its a hybrid app) everything works but when I run the test I get the following:

[image: Test failure]

Does somebody know why the scoped variable is still undefined? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When instantiating your controller, you should also inject any other services it needs.

AngularJS has a cool trick btw where you can use underscores in names:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$location_, _LocationDbService_) {
        // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        // Create the controller
        ctrl = $controller('LocationsCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $location : _$location_,
            LocationDbService : _LocationDbService_
        });
        location = _$location_; //thx to the underscores you could use '$location' as name instead of 'location'
        locationDbService = _LocationDbService_;
    }));
```

Next you should mock the service call:

```
it('should be able to retrieve all stored locations',
    function () {
        spyOn(locationDbService , 'getAll').andCallFake(function (success, fail) {
             var results = {};
             results.rows = new Array(5);
             success(null, results);
        });
        expect(scope.numberOfLocations).toBeUndefined();
        scope.getLocations();
        expect(scope.numberOfLocations).toBe(5);
    });
```

The service should have tests of its own.

Comment: You should also mock your service call, so you can test your controller as a unit. I'll update my answer wit han example.